# Generating a random list just using select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following code:

```
create table test 
(
  name varchar2(20 byte) 
);

insert into test values ('Fred');
insert into test values ('Wilma');
insert into test values ('Betty');
insert into test values ('Barny');

commit;

select * from test order by dbms_random.random;
```

Of course the select statement will create a random list with exactly 4 entries in this case. Is there a way to change the `select` statement so that the list can be expanded to more or less than 4 entries without the need to using PL?

Comment: You want to select X times random row from table test?

Comment: Yes - Retrieve X rows containing random rows from table test

Comment: `select t.* from test t,(select rownum rn from dual connect by level <=2) a                                 
order by dbms_random.random;` Generates 8 rows(number of rows=4*level2=8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a self cross-join to square the number of rows available, order that result randomly, and get the first X rows; assuming that X is lower than the square of the number of rows, e.g. with four source rows there are 16 results form the cross join, and with X as 10 in this example you get what you want:

```
select * from (
  select t1.name from test t1
  cross join test t2
  order by dbms_random.value
)
where rownum <= 10;

NAME                
--------------------
Betty
Betty
Fred
Betty
Wilma
Betty
Fred
Wilma
Barny
Barny

10 rows selected.
```

You could do the same thing with a hierarchical query to generate the extra rows:

```
select * from (
  select * from test
  connect by level < 3
  order by dbms_random.value
)
where rownum <= 10;

NAME                
--------------------
Fred
Fred
Barny
Wilma
Betty
Betty
Wilma
Betty
Wilma
Wilma

10 rows selected.
```

Each time the query is run the 10 (X) rows are different.

If X is larger then you can increase the number of levels. With `level < 3` the inner query generates 20 rows; with `level < 4` you get 84, etc.

If your source table is large you may want to be more restrictive, e.g. add `prior` clauses, so the number of rows (and amount of memory required) doesn't get out of control. From your simplified example it's hard to guess exactly what restrictions you'd need. You could, for instance, and assuming 'name' is actually a unique key, do something like:

```
select * from (
  select * from test
  connect by level < 10
  and prior name = name
  and prior dbms_random.value is not null
  order by dbms_random.value
)
where rownum <= 10;
```

The inner query now only gets 36 rows with the `level < 10` restriction. You will need to test with real data volumes and adjust for sensible results and performance.